# Why wont my results display correctly?

Tags: php, cookies

Everything works as intended except one thing. My cookies are setting properly because they will display when I want them to; however, my if statements with the isset()'s are not producing the correct output. It is using my else statement and thus telling me that my cookies are not set. Even though they are set and this can be checked multiple ways. What am I missing?

```
?>
<p class="php">You are logged in as: <?php echo $_POST['login'] . "."; ?></p>

<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE['$user']))
{
echo "A cookie is set:" . $_COOKIE['$user'];
}
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['$admin']))
{
echo "A cookie is set:" . $_COOKIE['$Eadmin'];
}
else
{
echo "No cookies set.";
}print_r($_COOKIE);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Delete your "$" in the cookie name

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you have `$` in `$_COOKIE` keys? Delete `$` from cookie name. Also I think this is wrong: `$_COOKIE['Eadmin']`, it should be `$_COOKIE['admin']`.

```
?>
<p class="php">You are logged in as: <?php echo $_POST['login'] . "."; ?></p>

<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
echo "A cookie is set:" . $_COOKIE['user'];
}
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['admin']))
{
echo "A cookie is set:" . $_COOKIE['admin'];
}
else
{
echo "No cookies set.";
}print_r($_COOKIE);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure all your cookie settings are set in php.ini file

Answer (score -1):

Try double quotes ,

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["$user"]))
```